# type conversion issue in using createprocess()

Tags: c++, casting

I am using a command line app which expects parameters to generate the desired output. I am trying to using `createprocess()` in `CPP` to call the app and pass parameters. I have a difficulty in type conversion . . It says `const char*` isn't compatible with `LPTSTR`.

If I say

```
char a[]="param 1 param2";
createprocess("C:\\exmpl.exe",a,......)
```

I used `L"C:\\exmpl.exe"` but its not working . .

Comment: This is not your actual code. It is therefore not helpful to the people trying to help you.

Answer (score 1):

`CreateProcess` requires a mutable (non-`const`) string for this parameter. You are apparently  passing in a `const` string.

Next time please paste the actual code you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not `CreateProcess`? Regardless, try with

```
_T("C:\\exmpl.exe")
```

This macro will expand your string to a wide string accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo . . It's CreateProcess

Comment: The compiler says const char * is not compatible with LPCWSTR

Comment: @Eric which one is it. First you say it's `LPTSTR` and now `LPCWSTR`.

Comment: The first parameter in CreateProcess is LPCTSTR and second is LPTSTR . .I tried _T,TEXT(),L" " . . nothing is working for me

Comment: @Eric have you looked only for type conversions?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
TCHAR a[] = TEXT("param 1 param2");
CreateProcess(TEXT("C:\\exmp1.exe", a, ...);
```

The TEXT macro is used to change your string to UNICODE if your app is set to use UNICODE.

Comment: what if later on you don't want to use unicode? You'd have to go all over the code to replace these occurences. The proper way is using `_T` instead (see my answer).

Comment: Eric, that's an extremely unhelpful thing to say. *What, exactly*, is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, new answer:

Watch the 2nd parameter, it must be a TCHAR* (char* in ANSI or wchar_t* in UNICODE).
Don't use CONST CHAR*, or say, don't simply pass "param1 param2" to the 2nd parameter, do it like this:

```
TCHAR param[] = TEXT("param1 param2");
CreateProcess(TEXT("my exe"), param, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also set your VC project to multibyte charset.
Just go to project properties and at the general tab you can see char set.